# kdb/Q How to iterate on a function x number of times?

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, iterator, iteration, kdb

I'm new to kdb/Q, what is the equivalent of iteration, where I need to run a function 10 times?

In Python, it would be something like creating some kind of iterator, using a while loop to run the function and add 1 to the iterator, and stopping when the iterator has reached 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native approach is to use accumulators/iterators/over/scan as per: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#do

```
q){x+1}/[10;1000]
1010
q)
q){x+1}\[10;1000]
1000 1001 1002 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 1010
```

e.g. run `{x+1}` 10 times with a starting value of 1000

There is also a `do` keyword which is useful for performing an operation N times without needing to carrying the output from one run the next: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/do/

Comment: Thanks, what about if I had a function that changed some items in a list, and I wanted to run that 10 times?

Comment: Same concept but it depends on if you need to pass intermediate values into the next iterations or if you can just modify a global variable. e.g. `{@[x;2?til count x;:;2?100]}\[10;1 2 3 4]` versus ```list:1 2 3 4;do[10;@[`list;2?til count list;:;2?100]]```

Comment: Got it, thank you for the information. I think the Do accumulator will help in this case.